# How to get a JSON value from a variable

Tags: javascript, json, variables

suppose I have `{"data": {"243232": {"id": "testid","name": "test" } }}`

so when I do

`var  a = data.243232.id`;
 `alert(a);` // it gives me `testid.`

but when I do like

```
    var c = 243232; 
    var d = data.c.id;
    alert(d) //it gives as undefined.
```

so how to get correct value when i alert d in above case thanks.

Comment: Please accept a correct answer by clicking the green question mark beside the answer that was the best

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the other notation `var a = data['243232'].id`

Remember all objects in JS are really just associative arrays.

Object keys just a variable in js and thus require proper naming

the variable naming rules are.

- The first character must be a letter
  (either uppercase or lowercase) or an
  underscore (_), or a dollar sign ($).
- Subsequent characters can be letters,
  numbers, underscores, or dollar signs
  in JavaScript Variables.
- The JavaScript Variable name can't be
  a reserved word of JavaScript, see
  details of JavaScript Reserved
  Characters

JSON normally uses an eval() function to turn the string into a data-structure.  This allows for incorrect keys.  If you want to reference an improper key, you need to use the associative array method.

As for you addition

```
var c = 243232; 
var d = data[c].id;
alert(d) //it gives as undefined.
```

Will work

Answer (score 6):

Use `data[c].id`.

In JavaScript, `.prop` is syntactic sugar for `["prop"]`. The bracket notation allows you to use values which would be invalid when using `.` (such as `background-image`) and variables.

Comment: The . is not really a reference to the []. [] and . are parsed entirely differently. The main part being that with the .notation the value is parsed as a Key Variable thus it must conform to variable naming rules.  The [] on the other hand are parsed as a string literal or value, which allows any characters. Take a look at the JS CFG.